# passing user credentials to web service

Tags: web-services

I have the following scenario:

- I have an application (html files + javascripts hosted in a webserver)
- There is a SOAP web service that we need to develop.
- Web service will be called from java script (AJAX calls).
- User will access the application in intranet scenario. Users are validated against active drectory.
- Requirement states that user need to be logging in using logged in users network credentials. There should not be a login screen shown to user.
- Web service interfaces need to be invoked with logged in users credentials. A login inteface of web service specifically needs to be called as first call.

I have a specific question on how to pass user credential to web service.

- I am planning to configure Integrated windows authentication (NTLM) for web application to avoid login screen.
- However I do not know a way to capture and send user id and password to login interface of web service.
  Most of the questions and answers around this topic has been for microsoft technlogies. Any specific ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research and several blog posts pointed me to Kerberos authentication and a single sign on framework. With NTLM i cannot delegate credentials to web service. However with Kerberos i can. I will be using SPNEGO and delegate the credentials after authentication. Please refer to below link for further details.
http://spnego.sourceforge.net/